# Second print page header with dynamic page size

Tags: html, css, printing

I want to print a dynamic list of `article`s in a column layout with the same header on each page. The list being dynamic, I don't know how many pages there will be nor on which article a page break will occur. The items are `page-break-inside: avoid;`.

The html:

```html
<table style="width: 100%">
    <thead><tr><td>
        <header>This is the header</header>
    </td></tr></thead>
    <tbody><tr><td>
        <div class="cols">
            <article>article 1</article>
            <article>article 2</article>
            <article>article 3</article>
            <article>article 4</article>
            <article>article 5</article>
            <article>article 6</article>
            <article>article 7</article>
            <article>article 8</article>
            <article>article 9</article>
            <article>article 10</article>
        </div>
    </td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```

The CSS:

```css
.cols {
    columns: 2 auto;
}

article {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    height: 280px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Which should create something like:

[image: Ideal layout]

The order of the articles is not important, nor on what page they appear.

However... This causes causes the top articles in all columns but the first and on only the first page to have a top gap:

[image: Attempt 1]

**Attempt 2**: inline-block

```css
article {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Now all top articles on the first page have the gap. (and only during printing, the screen display is ok)

[image: More gaps]

Aargh CSS! 
I've also tried playing with a `display: fixed` header with(out) fake table thead placeholder but also didn't come to a satisfactory solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: So to clarify, you want the `This is the header` to be on top of both article 1 and article 4 in the screenshots? And you *don't* want that gap between the header and article, correct?

Comment: It has to appear on the top of each printed page. I've added a picture of the "end goal".